# MySQL how to show rows that also does not match where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, where-in

I have this query:

```
SELECT `y78f2_students`.`firstname` , `y78f2_students`.`lastName` , `y78f2_students`.`student_id`,`y78f2_attendance`.`is_present`, `y78f2_attendance`.`note`, `y78f2_attendance`.`thedate`  
FROM `y78f2_students`
INNER JOIN `y78f2_enrolls` ON `y78f2_enrolls`.`student_id` = `y78f2_students`.`student_id` 
INNER JOIN `y78f2_attendance` ON `y78f2_attendance`.`student_id` = `y78f2_students`.`student_id` 
WHERE `y78f2_enrolls`.`term` = 'Term 2 2016' 
AND `y78f2_enrolls`.`crn_class` = 'Math1R1' 
and `y78f2_attendance`.`thedate` = '2016-01-24'
ORDER BY thedate desc
```

This query returns only the rows where the date is '2016-01-24'. Currently that is just one row: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNcZR.png

I need to show all rows where `term` = 'Term 2 2016' and crn_class` = 'Math1R1' and also where the date is not set as yet. In order words I want to show all students in the class and if the date is not set for these students yet, it will show null.
This is what I would like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCUy2.png

So in summary I need to show rows where the clause is met and those where the date would be null or not exist yet.
How can I write this query?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:sql-server]?

Comment: you could just set a default value for the date and also check for that by adding an `OR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the conditions related to the joined tables from the end of the query, up to the table's respective `ON` clause for each join. Also, if you would like to return records for which no row yet exists in the `y78f2_attendance` table, that table should be `LEFT OUTER` joined, not `INNER` joined.

```
SELECT `y78f2_students`.`firstname` , `y78f2_students`.`lastName`,
    `y78f2_students`.`student_id`,`y78f2_attendance`.`is_present`, 
    `y78f2_attendance`.`note`, `y78f2_attendance`.`thedate`  
FROM `y78f2_students`
INNER JOIN `y78f2_enrolls` ON
    `y78f2_enrolls`.`student_id` = `y78f2_students`.`student_id`
    AND `y78f2_enrolls`.`crn_class` = 'Math1R1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN `y78f2_attendance` ON
    `y78f2_attendance`.`student_id` = `y78f2_students`.`student_id`
    AND (`y78f2_attendance`.`thedate` IS NULL OR `y78f2_attendance`.`thedate` = '2016-01-24')
WHERE `y78f2_enrolls`.`term` = 'Term 2 2016' 
ORDER BY thedate desc
```

Comment: Thank you @Asaph, it worked great. Just what I needed. Thanks again!